# NewLateBinding and Conversions in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a method which has the following line of code:

```
string PrimaryKey = Conversions.ToString(NewLateBinding.LateGet(obj, null, "PrimaryKeyString", new object[0], null, null, null));
```

and I get an error telling that NewLateBinding and Conversions does not exist in the current context.
I am using .Net 4.0 and visual studio 2012. I am new to .NET programming. I am not sure why this error. I got this code from my colleague to fix it.

Please help me with this. How can I fix it?..

Comment: See [NewLateBinding.LateGet Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.newlatebinding.lateget.aspx). You'll need to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. Also, try changing that to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet`.

Comment: For future reference, check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.newlatebinding(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Please follow the MSDN Suggestion: This helper method is not meant to be called directly from your code.

Answer (score 3):

Please add reference of Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

NewLateBinding Class exist in Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices namespace in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll assembly.

[NewLateBinding msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.newlatebinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)